# webpack module node produces error EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Trying to learn webpack but I keep getting this error whenever I introduce the module node into webpack.config.js

## Error output:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js
Module build failed: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:731:19)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:486:20)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:534:19)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.addConfig (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:146:32)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.findConfigs (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:102:30)
    at buildConfigChain (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:61:13)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:360:58)
    at File.initOptions (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:216:65)
    at new File (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:139:24)
    at Pipeline.transform (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
    at transpile (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:41:20)
    at Object.module.exports (/Users/noah/.Trash/02_02/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:138:12)
```

## webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: 'build',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

## src/main.js

```
const $ = require('jquery');

$('#target').html('hello world!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `babel-core` and `babel-loader` had not yet been saved to my package.json. Derp.